# Trying to load an array based of values from 2 other arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say my 1D char array looks like:

> [E, A, D, C, C]

and my 2D char array looks like:

> [ [E, A, D, B, C], [d, a, d, e, c], [b, a, , e, a] ]

and I'm trying to create an array of question statistics where it is populated by how many times a question was answered correctly by each student. It should look something like {1,3,2,0,2}

Here is what I tried:

```
public void produceQuestionStatistics(char [] correctAnswers, char [][] studentAnswers, int fillLvl, int fillLvl2)
{
    double [] questionMarks = new double [20];
    int sum;
    int row = 0;
    int col;
    while(row < fillLvl2)
    {
        sum = 0;
        col = 0; 
        while(col < fillLvl2)
        {
            if(Character.toUpperCase(studentAnswers[row][col]) == correctAnswers[col])
            {
                sum++;
            }
            col++;
        }
        questionMarks[row] = sum;
        row++;
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < questionMarks.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(questionMarks[i]);
    }
}
```

Where fillLvl = 3 (rows of students) and fillLvl2 = 5 (number of questions)

Comment: You are ignoring `fillLvl` parameter, using `fillLvl2` twice.

Comment: I'm trying to iterate through the correcAnswers array because I need the questionMarks array to be populated with 5 values

Comment: What about your implementation isn't working?  As @dasblinkenlight mentioned, you aren't using fillLv1 at all.  Should the `while(row < fillLvl2)` be `while(row < fillLv1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understood why do you use `fillLvl` and `fillLvl2` variables because the array already have this information. I do this implementation, who works, hope this will help you.

```
char[] correctAnswers = {'E', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'C'};
char[][] studentAnswers = {{'E', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C'}, {'d', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'c'}, {'b', 'a', ' ', 'e', 'a'}};

int answersNumber = correctAnswers.length;
int[] correctStudentAnswers = new int[answersNumber];

for (char[] studentAnswer : studentAnswers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < answersNumber; i++) {
        if (Character.toUpperCase(studentAnswer[i]) == correctAnswers[i]) {
            correctStudentAnswers[i]++;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(correctStudentAnswers));
```

Output

```
[1, 3, 2, 0, 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/ZmZWE8)

Comment: Hmm for some reason I get a index out of bounds exception

Comment: What are your input datasets ?

Comment: It's exactly the same as the data set above

Comment: I edited my answers to add a link to Java Online Runner. Because it works well on my computer and on online runner. Are you sure about the OutOfBounds Exception ? In which line do you have a problem ?

Comment: line 13 I get an array out of bound exception [5], I'm not sure why though

Comment: the length of my correctAnswers Array is 20, I used fillLvl to accomodate if more questions would be added

Comment: No. no. no. Set your array size to your number of questions. why do you want to set a more big char array than you need ?

Comment: To accomodate more answers if needed. I got it though thank you!

Comment: @Mcbever : You're welcome. If my solution solved your problem, you might consider clicking on the check mark to the left of the question to mark your question resolved.